# Selenium - Java - findelements by classname does not return all elements

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Below is my code snippet.

```
List<WebElement> e=driver.findElements(By.className("<this class name>"));  
System.out.println(e.size());
```

There are 50 elements with this class name in the page, however, only 40 are returned. The div class being queried above is nested within other div classes. However, all elements are in exact same structure. Elements are structured in tabular format of 5 columns and 10 rows.

I am able to access the elements that are not returned by using their respective xpath.

Selenium : 3.11.0

Browser - Chrome Version 65.0.3325.181

ChromeDriver 2.36.540470

Appreciate any suggestions on resolving this issue to return all 50 elements.

Adding more information in the question for future references.
- By default only 7 rows of data are visible. Needed to scroll down to see rest of the rows.
- Validated the same by using .isDisplayed() for the element and all elements on 8th row and below returned false as expected.
- immediately after the page is displayed, inspecting the page and searching manually, all elements are present in the page.

Comment: Could you share the entire HTML page?

Comment: I believe this can happen if the page is not fully processed the moment you call findElements. Try adding Thread.yield or Thread.sleep prior to your code to see if anything changes

Comment: if those elements are being added dynamically they could be not added to DOM yet by the moment you execute your script lines.

Comment: Hi @SirVaulterScoff,  you are right. I tried with sleep before executing the code, it worked fine. There possibly is fraction of delay as manually I could always find the element as I inspected the page. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Hi @AlexeyR. Sure, adding sleep helped and resolved the issue. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hi @Anand, sorry I could not share the page. However, issue has been resolved after adding sleep before executing my code. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If you expected a fixed number of elements you can use `wait`. It will allow the page to fully render and all elements might be visible.

2 ways (work the same way):

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public Boolean apply(WebDriver input) {
        List<WebElement> e=driver.findElements(By.className("<this class name>"));  
        return e.size() == 50;
    }
};
```

Or using lambda expression:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
    wait.until(driver -> {
        List<WebElement> e=driver.findElements(By.className("<this class name>"));  
        return e.size() == 50;
    };
```

Comment: Hi @Rafal Laskowski, It appears there was a slight delay in page completion, so adding sleep for few seconds helped and resolved the issue. As per my edit of questions, elements on 8th row and below are not visible. Need to scroll down to make them visible. Thanks for your time and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question to validate if all the **50** elements are **visible** within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) or not you can induce [WebDriverWait](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) with [ExpectedConditions](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) clause as [visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy-org.openqa.selenium.By-) for all the elements identified through the *Locator Strategy*  and validate as follows :

```
if(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.className("<this class name>"))).size() == 50)
    System.out.println("All elements visible");
else
    System.out.println("All elements NOT visible");
```

Comment: Hi @DebanjanB, elements were not visible. I have edited the question to reflect further information. As per the suggestion above, waiting before executing my code helped. It appears there is slight delay in complete page execution. Thanks for your time and suggestion.